# Как в JavaFx располагать компоненты на форме

Tags: java, javafx

Пытаюсь изучать JavaFX. Пробую расположить графические элементы в окне.
Fxml не использую, пока еще не умею с ним работать.
У меня есть два текстовых поля, в одну линию.
Далее идут в две колонки два комбо и три кнопки.
И в самом низу расположены три текстовых поля, в одну линию.
Я хочу, чтобы все Box-ы были растянуты на все окно (по горизонтали или вертикали соответственно).
Вот код:

```
Pane pane = new Pane();
HBox hBoxTop = new HBox(5.0);
TextField textTop1 = new TextField();
TextField textTop2 = new TextField();
hBoxTop.getChildren().addAll(textTop1, textTop2);
HBox hBoxC = new HBox(5.0);
ComboBox<String> combo1 = new ComboBox<>();
ComboBox<String> combo2 = new ComboBox<>();
hBoxC.getChildren().addAll(new VBox(5.0, combo1, combo2));
Button button1 = new Button();
Button button2 = new Button();
Button button3 = new Button();
hBoxC.getChildren().addAll(new VBox(5.0, button1, button2, button3));
HBox hBoxBot = new HBox(5.0);
TextField textBot1 = new TextField();
TextField textBot2 = new TextField();
TextField textBot3 = new TextField();
hBoxBot.getChildren().addAll(textBot1, textBot2, textBot3);
      
pane.getChildren().addAll(hBoxTop, hBoxC, hBoxBot);
Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 600.0, 400.0);
```

Я ожидал, что все Box-ы будут расположены одни под другим, но они все помещаются в верхней части окна.
Подскажите как правильно все это делается.
Вот что я хочу получить:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Чтобы "боксы" размещались один под другим, нужно помещать их в VBox, а его уже в pane (либо просто использовать VBox вместо Pane).

Comment: Также возможно вам подойдет один GridPane вместо нескольких HBox-ов.

Comment: Это решило одну проблему. А как сделать, что бы мой HBox (hBoxTop) был длинной во все окно, а шириной чуть более текстовых полей? Т.е. чтобы следующие VBox располагались под ним. А щас они располагаются слева от него

Comment: Расширять до ширины окна можно вот так: `hBoxTop.setPrefWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);` Остальное не понятно что там у вас, добавьте скриншот хотя бы.

Comment: картинку добавил, там показаны все боксы, а в них уже будут расположены кнопки, поля и т.д. Кстати сразу вопрос, те два VBox их может быть тоже надо положить в один HBox?
А вот с hBoxTop.setPrefWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE) получилась какая-то ерунда, фото выложил. Черное - это кусок hBoxTop

Comment: Перефразирую вопрос, просто подскажите как правильно расположить на форме боксы представленные на первом рисунке, только без жесткой фиксации их размера, т.е. если окно увеличить они тоже должны увеличиться.

Comment: В общем, для текстовых полей, чтобы они расширялись по ширине внутри HBox, нужно делать `HBox.setHgrow(textBot1, Priority.ALWAYS);` Также можно сделать чтобы VBox-ы тоже расширялись (например, `HBox.setHgrow(vbox1, Priority.ALWAYS)`), но это не повлияет на размер их содержимого (кнопок и комбо). Возможно придется задать для них просто минимальную ширину.

Comment: а можно как-то сделать чтобы одни VBox не наезжал на другой? Как на рисунке показано. При этом не задавая их координаты

Comment: Если вы делали именно так как у вас в коде, то они и не должны наезжать.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась, когда root поменял на VBox